# VB2010 Watch Window

Tags: debugging, events, hidden, watch

I've looked all over and I can't find out how to do this.  I know it's possible as I have seen it implemented in other code.

I have a ton of events in some classes which makes scrolling through the watch window on the object tedious and cumbersome.  I would like to keep the events from showing in the watch window, much like  will allow me to hide private or non-critical variables, constants, etc...

I'm sure this can be done as when I debug code, that I know has events, the events do not show up in the objet model in the watch window.  I have read about a debugproxy, but haven't tried it yet.  This is really just because it annnoys me and makes debugging other parts of the code harder so I haven't spent much time on implementing a solution, just searching for information online.

Can you advise?